# Ruby on Rails - how to input line breaks into textarea so when the content is displayed, line breaks are also there?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am the admin of a site, and I have a special textarea that only I populate (i.e. I am not concerned about someone trying to mess with it to wreck my site). I want to put some line breaks when I input in this textarea, so that when it is displayed there are some decent line breaks.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `simple_format` helper in rails.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html

It will interpret line breaks and insert the correct HTML so that the text is displayed correctly.